Update data after query fetching on success with vue query v5
I am using @tanstack/vue-query package, and I am not sure how to update data after the query fetching is completed successfully.
I can write data update logic in query function but I want to extract useQuery into separate composables function.
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/vue-query";

const title = ref('')
const body = ref('')

const query = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["post", route.params.id],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const data = await api.get(`/posts/${route.params.id}`);

    // This data update logic is tied with query function
    title.value = data.data.data.title,
    body.value = data.data.data.body,

    return data;
  },
});
</script>

To
composables/useGetPost.js
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/vue-query";

export const useGetPost = (id) => {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["post", id],
    queryFn: () => api.get(`/posts/${id}`),
  });

  return {
    data
  };
};

and use in the component
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useGetPost } from './composables/useGetPost.js'

const title = ref('')
const body = ref('')

const { data } = useGetPost(route.params.id)

// Update logic
// update title and body value after data is fetched
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

